# Batch is not able to see folders with "."

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I just made my bat script which would create folder structure, but I found some issue with creating new sub-folders for folder which contains dots.

Example: Company s.r.o

So this folder will be skipped cause it contains "." in folder name. Is there any workaround or solution for this?

My code:

```
FOR /d %%A IN (*.) DO ( 
  if NOT EXIST "%%A\DATOVKY" ( mkdir "%%A\DATOVKY" )
```

Comment: As a work around can't you rename it to s-r-o ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is NOT that the folder "doesn't work", but that your wildcard in the FOR excludes all folders with an internal "." in the name.
You are explicitly looking for folders whose names don't contain any dots at all.
Change it as below and it will process ALL folders.

```
FOR /d %%A IN (*) DO ( 
if NOT EXIST "%%A\DATOVKY" ( mkdir "%%A\DATOVKY" )
```

P.S. I do hope you realize there is a ")" missing at the end ?

Comment: Ofc, I do, its not full code. And I found workaround anyway. :)